# How is this constraint convex?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I have the following constraint

$$\sum_{i=2}^{n}p_i\leq \sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\log(1+ax_i)$$

and

$$p_i \geq 0$$

where $a > 0$ is constant, and $p_i \geq 0$ and $x_i \geq 0$ are the optimization variables. I want to know how this constraint is convex. Any help in this regard will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: just to clarify, is $a$ fixed? or is it a variable?

Comment: @SiongThyeGoh it is fix value. I also modify in my question

Comment: So since this one is proving *convexity*, you _can_ use constructive arguments and composition rules---unlike the questions where you have been asking about *non-convexity*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since  $f(x)=-\log(1+ax)$ is a convex function,

$$\sum_{i=2}^{n}p_i- \sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\log(1+ax_i)$$

is a convex function, since sum of convex function is convex and sum of $p_i$ is clearly a convex function as well.

Hence $$\sum_{i=2}^{n}p_i- \sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\log(1+ax_i) \le 0$$ is a convex set.

The constraints $p_i \geq 0$ is also convex and intersection of convex set is convex.

Comment: Thank you so much. Your answer is very easy to understand. If we have another constraint which is $\sum_{i=1}^N x_i \leq \text{some constant}$ even then the above constraint will remain convex? (I think so it will remain convex since $\sum_{i=1}^N x_i$ is a linear combination so it is also convex therefore the overall the constraint in my OP will remain convex)

Comment: yes, you are just intersecting with another halfspace, which is convex and intersection fo convex set is convex.

Comment: Sorry for disturbing but you mean halfspace and not hyperplane right?

Comment: yes, halfspace... sorry for earlier typo.